# Connect spark to hive with url

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a terrible times when I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue.
We have on server installed spark2-shell, kerberos, hive, beeline and impala.
I'm  trying to execute some queries in spark2 but I'm getting permission error permission="execute". I have two databases. Lets call them vegetables and fruits.
I can freely execute queries on fruits in spark2-shell>, impala-shell>, hive> and beeline>. Vegetables is on the other hand restricted for me, unless I provide connection string to impala-shell> and beeline>, then I can freely do whatever I want with vegetables.
What I think might happened is I don't have those permission for default user and I have to provide it to pyspark or scala (doesn't really matter which I'll use) with kerberos. I've read a lot of articles about it and still I couldn't resolve that issue. I tried to connect by url in sparkcontext but It didn't found driver.
Could you please help me?

Comment: What if you authenticate with [`kinit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/kinit.html) beforehand?

Comment: Did you use `enableHiveSupport()` to create the `SparkSession`?

Comment: I've authenticate with kinit before execution. Otherwise nothing would work.
I also enabled hive supprot in spark session